# Trying to create AzureADUser Cannot bind PasswordProfile

Tags: powershell, azure, office365, azure-powershell

I'm trying to create Azure AD user but I keep getting same error.

> Cannot bind parameter 'PasswordProfile'.

I've tried many solutions but none has solved it.

```
$DN = $User.DisplayName
$FN = $User.GivenName
$LN = $User.SurName
$UPN = $User.UserPrincipalName
$UL = $User.UsageLocation 
$MNN = $User.MailNickName
$PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = $User.PasswordP

[boolean]$AE = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($User.AccountEnabled)

New-AzureADUser `
-DisplayName = $DN `
-GivenName = $FN `
-SurName = $LN `
-UserPrincipalName = $UPN `
-UsageLocation = $UL `
-MailNickName = $MNN `
-PasswordProfile = $PasswordProfile `
-AccountEnabled = $AE
```

[Powershell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tARzD.png)

Comment: $User is for the csv-file:
foreach ($User in $csv)

Answer (score 0):

In your cmdlet to create User, you could not use `=`. Modify your cmdlet like below:

```
New-AzureADUser `
-DisplayName  $DN `
-GivenName  $FN `
-SurName  $LN `
-UserPrincipalName  $UPN `
-UsageLocation  $UL `
-MailNickName  $MNN `
-PasswordProfile  $PasswordProfile `
-AccountEnabled  $AE
```

Please refer to this link about how to use :[New-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: Oh! Yes i see that now, tnx for the help!